# React component syntax using HTML and CSS

Tags: reactjs

Attempting to create a simple like/unlike component with React. How can I render this component with `<i class="fal fa-thumbs-down">` markup and classes to style the icons? My syntax here is off somewhere.

```
class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return (
        <i class="fal fa-thumbs-down"></i>
        { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: false }) }
      );
    }

    return (
      <i class="fal fa-thumbs-up"></i>
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (
   <i class="fal fa-thumbs-down" onClick={ () => this.setState({ liked: !this.state.liked}) } />
)
```

I made three changes:

1. `onClick` is a *prop* passed to i, just like `class` is.
2. i is now self-closing
3. instead of conditionally rendering, the logic in onClick is conditional (it flips the existing state when clicked)

Also, I'd **strongly** recommend switching over to functional components instead of class components. They're much cleaner (and more fun!) to work with.

Comment: Any idea why I'd get `Unexpected token '<'` on the `i`?

Comment: @noclist Are you sure you're using the file extension  `.jsx`, not `.js`? JSX is a superset of JavaScript, and you need to be using JSX to use the embedded html tags.